# Payment methods render list and Place Order Button missing on custom Checkout module

Tags: magento2

I have recently installed the magento2.0.1 version and integrated the extensions Payone for Magento 2 and IWD OPC checkout [extension] for Magento 2.

Now when I access the checkout page, I cannot see the any of the payment methods and there is no Place Order Button.

Has anyone encountered this before? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento needs a shipping method. Do you have at least one shipping method enabled?

If so, try re-selecting the default shipping method. 
I have noticed that clicking a shipping option is required before it will show the payment options, which seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, I have the shipping methods enabled. When I select or re-select the shipping method, no shipping cost is added to the total and the form displays an error as "Unable to save shipping information. Please check, input data".